# How to setup multiple clients in Vue apollo v4?

Tags: vue.js, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I have 2 different servers (graphql, rest) and trying to setup multiple clients in my vue app.

Here is my setup `apollo.provider.js`

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core'
import { RestLink } from 'apollo-link-rest';
import { provide } from 'vue'
import { ApolloClients } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

// HTTP connection to the API
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'https://reqres.in/graphql'
})

// Set `RestLink` with your endpoint
const restLink = new RestLink({ 
    uri: "https://reqres.in"
});

// Cache implementation
const cache = new InMemoryCache()

// Create the graphql client
const graphqlClient = new ApolloClient({
    cache: cache,
    link: httpLink
})

// Create the rest client
const restClient = new ApolloClient({
    cache: cache,
    link: restLink
})

export const provider = provide(ApolloClients, {
    default: graphqlClient,
    restClient: restClient
  })
```

This is not working, however I can use each client seperately by doing

```
import { createApolloProvider } from '@vue/apollo-option'

export const provider = createApolloProvider({
    defaultClient: graphqlClient // or restClient
})
```

Please help me understand how to use both clients.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I mixed up between "options API" and "composition API"

considering my setup uses "options API" this solution works.

```
export const provider = createApolloProvider({
    clients: {
        graphqlClient,
        restClient
    },
    defaultClient: graphqlClient,
})
```